# GitLab - change personal email to university email

Tags: gitlab

My personal email is showing on GitLab when I contribute (for example by pushing commits), even though I am logged in using my university email. Is there any way to change the email?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running Linux you might have set the git attribute user.email to your personal email.
Try to change it with:

```
git config --global user.email "YOUR EMAIL"
```

Omit `--global` if you want to handle it on a project basis.

More information can be found [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup).

Comment: yes it was indeed a setting in git itself, not GitLab. Thank you